# How to implement an email verification system with Go&MongoDB?

Tags: go

I currently give JWT tokens from my /signup:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2ODMwMjcwOTUsInR5cGUiOiJhd2FpdGluZy12ZXJpZmljYXRpb24iLCJ1dWlkIjoiNjQ0ZmEzMTc1MmQwODdhYjg1NmE2NTA3In0.nHZg6RGkYxWM2vy4YyFHxyq_Snb3o9NpoRiMgEKnY2o
```

which is just:

```bash
{
  "exp": 1683027095,
  "type": "awaiting-verification",
  "uuid": "644fa31752d087ab856a6507"
}
```

and can't wrap my head around how can I even send an email for verification. I planned to create a separate collection called "emailcodes", generate a random 6-digit number, let's say 123123, and insert into the collection like:

```bash
{
  "uuid": "644fa31752d087ab856a6507"
  "code": 123123
  "exp": 5-minutes-in-unix
}
```

and take the code from whitelisted (tokens that is type is awaiting-verification) endpoint /code-verification

The problem is, I do not know how can I send emails without screwing everything up like sending the same email a dozen times, etc. Is there a GoLang library for this? If there isn't how can I implement a system for this that even I cant screw it up?

I already verify if the email is valid and reachable with https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/AfterShip/email-verifier?utm_source=godoc

..Help?

Comment: Why would your code send the same email a dozen times?

Comment: I even don't know. I don't trust myself on systems I build that interact with users directly.

Comment: MongoDb has official Go driver: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/

Comment: I know about that Çetin, I need help on implementing an email system. I already have a middleware that assigns cluster connections for every request. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Your question title is about email address verification.  But reading the question, it sounds like you actually want to *send* emails.  So shouldn't the title be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explaining I think you should prefer good references with great use cases:

### Mailing packages in Go

- Go's STD can handle this for sure: https://pkg.go.dev/net/mail (But, please have a look at the second option, too)
- I prefer to use this third-party package, coz I found it more flexible and user-friendly - [jordan-wright/email](https://github.com/jordan-wright/email). Additionally, I use this package for a while and got no issues with it. So, confidently recommended by my humble experience as a Gopher. BTW, there are too many other open-source options if you want to play with them. Thanks to the Go's great community!

### Implementing email verification

- Firstly, you need to implement mailing service, and then verification. Here is the example using [jordan-wright/email](https://github.com/jordan-wright/email). [Reference](https://github.com/techschool/simplebank/blob/master/mail/sender.go).

```golang
package mail

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/smtp"

    "github.com/jordan-wright/email"
)

const (
    smtpAuthAddress   = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpServerAddress = "smtp.gmail.com:587"
)

type EmailSender interface {
    SendEmail(
        subject string,
        content string,
        to []string,
        cc []string,
        bcc []string,
        attachFiles []string,
    ) error
}

type GmailSender struct {
    name              string
    fromEmailAddress  string
    fromEmailPassword string
}

func NewGmailSender(name string, fromEmailAddress string, fromEmailPassword string) EmailSender {
    return &GmailSender{
        name:              name,
        fromEmailAddress:  fromEmailAddress,
        fromEmailPassword: fromEmailPassword,
    }
}

func (sender *GmailSender) SendEmail(
    subject string,
    content string,
    to []string,
    cc []string,
    bcc []string,
    attachFiles []string,
) error {
    e := email.NewEmail()
    e.From = fmt.Sprintf("%s <%s>", sender.name, sender.fromEmailAddress)
    e.Subject = subject
    e.HTML = []byte(content)
    e.To = to
    e.Cc = cc
    e.Bcc = bcc

    for _, f := range attachFiles {
        _, err := e.AttachFile(f)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to attach file %s: %w", f, err)
        }
    }

    smtpAuth := smtp.PlainAuth("", sender.fromEmailAddress, sender.fromEmailPassword, smtpAuthAddress)
    return e.Send(smtpServerAddress, smtpAuth)
}
```

- Email verification: Here is a brilliant blog post about this flow with the snippets which I believe can explain more clearly then I can do so at this time, so I'd refernce that: [Email Verification and Password Reset Flow using golang](https://dvignesh1496.medium.com/email-verification-and-password-reset-flow-using-golang-c8bd037101e8).
- If u just need to check of an email exists or not instead of checking ownership on that for the provider user, you can simply use this powerful Go package - [AfterShip/email-verifier](https://github.com/AfterShip/email-verifier).

Answer (score 0):

There several libraries available to send emails.

- Mailgun : https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go
- GoMail : https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail
- net/smtp : https://pkg.go.dev/net/smtp

Here is an example how we can use gomail.v2

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

// EmailSender
type EmailSender struct {
    Message *gomail.Message
    dailer  *gomail.Dialer
}

// NewEmailSender
func NewEmailSender() *EmailSender {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    dailer := gomail.NewDialer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "smtpEmail@example.com", "smtp-password")
    m.SetHeader("From", "from-email@gmail.com")

    return &EmailSender{
        Message: m,
        dailer:  dailer,
    }
}

// Send
func (es *EmailSender) Send(subject, to, message string) error {

    es.Message.SetHeader("To", to)
    es.Message.SetHeader("Subject", subject)
    es.Message.SetBody("text/plain", message)

    if err := es.dailer.DialAndSend(es.Message); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

// checks before sending the email
//   - code is valid
//   - email already sent
//   - code is expired or not
//
// TODO : Implement your checks

func ChecksBeforeEmailSend(code string) error {
    return errors.New("email already sent")
}

func main() {
    code := "123456"

    emailer := NewEmailSender()

    if err := ChecksBeforeEmailSend(code); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Check %v failed", err.Error()))
    }

    err := emailer.Send(
        "Verify your email", // subject
        "to@gmail.com", // to email
        fmt.Sprintf("Your verfication code is %d", code), // message
     )

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

*To prevent sending duplicate emails for a verification-code, you can use a field within the mongo db collection which will indicate that the email has already send for a particular user and code, check this field value before sending the email.*

for example

```
{
  "uuid": "644fa31752d087ab856a6507"
  "code": 123123
  "exp": 5-minutes-in-unix
  "sent" : true
}
```

*"sent" : true,*  indicates an email has already send for this user and code

We can add additional checks before sending the emails within `ChecksBeforeEmailSend`.